# Saving an UIImage and saving to an enum CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, enums, uiimage

I made multiple enum so that I can save a photo that the user took which is displayed in the UIImage.  However I do not know how to save and picture that is displayed in the UIImage.  I also want the user to select which enum he wants to save to so that I can sort the pictures into Genre.  I just want to have a starting point and I am stuck now.

```
-(void)setLabelTextForCategory:(MyFoodCategory)category
{
    switch(category) {
        case MyFoodCategoryVegetable:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"V";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryMeat:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"M";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryFish:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"P"; 
            break;
        case MyFoodCategorySweet:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"D";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: I want the user to take the photo in the app and then choose which category he wants to save the photo that he took using a picker view and then push save button which I did not make yet.  I want the user to sort the photo that he took. User can select the category from the main screen in the app and see the pictures that he sorted

Answer (score 0):

So, say you have an Image entity in your Core Data model. This entity will have, in your case, at least two attributes: imageData and genre. imageData is of type NSData and genre is of type Integer64 which, when made into a property when you generate your classes, will be an NSNumber. So, have your user select an image and genre. Then you can save like this:

```
    Image *theSavedImage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" 
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:myContext];
    theSavedImage.imageData = UIImageJpegRepresentation(mySelectedImage, 1.0);
    theSavedImage.genre = [NSNumber numberWithInt:mySelectedGenre];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [myContext save:&error];
```

Also, if you look around on Google, you will find that there is some debate as to whether storing images directly into Core Data is wise. It can be done, certainly. But some people recommend storing a file URL as an attribute on your managed object and writing the image data to the file system.

Edit in response to comment:

The *imageData* attribute should be binary, not the genre. The genre should be Integer64. In your generated header, these will be properties of types NSData and NSNumber, respectively. The NSNumber attribute (genre) is what you will save the selected enum value to, using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:mySelectedGenre];` Selecting a genre will have to be a separate step, as UIImagePickerController is intended to be used as-is and does not offer the user an opportunity to do anything but select an image, basically.

Comment: I currently do not have the genre type NSData do you mean Binary? Does this work with the enum that I created which I assigned numbers? And will I be able to make the user select which genre to save to using picker controller?